# ok button in record Form plugin in extjs

Tags: extjs

how to get the updated records,i am overriding the on Ok function to save changes in form.
1.i just override the on ok function,but not able to get modified record.

```
Ext.override(Ext.ux.grid.RecordForm , {
    onOK:function() {

            updateRecord1();
        }

});
function updateRecord1() {//alert('record');
var records =store.getModifiedRecords();
        if(!records.length) {
            return;
        }
        var data = [];
        Ext.each(records, function(r, i) {
            var o = r.getChanges();
            if(r.data.newRecord) {
                o.newRecord = true;
            }
            o[idName] = r.get(idName);
            data.push(o);
        });
        var o = {
             url:gl_acc.php
            ,method:'post'
            ,params:{
                 record:record.get('id'),
                 task:'update'
            }
        };
        Ext.Ajax.request(o);
    } // eo function commitChanges
```

Answer (score 0):

`var records = this.store.getModifiedRecords();`

Comment: i am overriding onok function of record form plugin by saki in extjs,i am not able to fetch the updated record.

Comment: I took a quick look at the source, and it seems that to get the store you need to refer to it via `this.store` or `this.grid.store`. Unless you have a global variable called `store`, calling `store.getModifiedRecords();` will not do anything (except raising an exception)

Comment: ya...when i try to alert records.length it shows zero..thats what i want to know how to get the updated record